# Insert the content of an array in a database in php

Tags: php, sql, database

I wrote this function that scrapes some content from a web page to my database. My issue is with my array variable `$lang`, everything works as I want when I test with `print_r($lang)`, but I am unable to insert the values in my DB because it looks like the array is empty when I used it in the second `foreach`.

Please guys, how can insert `$lang` in my DB properly? Here below is my code. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you!

```
<?php

$html = file_get_html($url);
$links = array();
$lang = array();
foreach ($html->find('div.blockshadow h1') as $i => $title) {
    $textValue = $title->plaintext;
    if (strpos($textValue, 'VF') !== false) {
        $lang[] = 'VF';
    } elseif (strpos($textValue, 'VOSTFR') !== false) {
        $lang[] = 'VOSTFR';
    } elseif (strpos($textValue, 'VO') !== false) {
        $lang[] = 'VO';
    }
}

foreach ($html->find('div.blockshadow iframe') as $key => $a) {
    $linkUrl = $a->src;
    $wpdb->insert(
            $table_name, array(
        'Idioma' => $lang,
        'Calidad' => ucwords("HDRIP"),
        'Enlace' => $linkUrl,
        'PID' => $return['ID'],
        'Tipo' => '3',
            )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not plan to split up your data into multiple tables and want to keep it all in one column, you can use [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode)/[serialize](http://php.net/serialize).

Which one of both you choose is pretty much up to you, but stay consistent.

When you read out your data, just use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)/[unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) and you get back your initial array.

Something like:

```
   $data = json_encode([
       'Idioma' => $lang,
       'Calidad' => ucwords("HDRIP"),
       'Enlace' => $linkUrl,
       'PID' => $return['ID'],
       'Tipo' => '3',
   ]);

   $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);
```

And for reading, you first want to select the data from your table like normal, but before using it, you have to [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)/[unserialize](http://php.net/unserialize) the column which yields this data.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the array into string, using the implode function and also do check if the value is empty or not, something like this.

```
$newLang = "";

if(!empty($lang))
{
   $newLang = implode(',',$lang);
}
```

And use the `$newLang` variable for the database, also inside the foreach loop you want to insert all the values present in the array, then use the above way, if you want specific values with each loop, then use `$newLang[$key]` .

Hope this helps.

PS: You can't insert array directly into table.

Comment: Thank you i was able to insert the data in the DB  but my concern is that the value get insert multiple time  please see this image  [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k24hSCIoBQA1iSPe2pUYFxQ_bDUqRs3g/view?usp=sharing)  3 time this case because we have just 3 $linkUrl , normally one $newLang match with one $linkUrl